# Как реализовать открытое хэширование?

Tags: c++, структуры, хеширование

До этого имел дело с закрытым хешированием, все понял, имеется функция, которая, если ячейка занята вычисляет новый адрес с помощью опробования. Сейчас же хочу попробовать сделать открытое хеширование. Нигде не могу найти именно код на языке C++ с реализацией открытого хеширования, что из себя представляет сам код. На словах понимаю, что у каждой ячейки есть свой массив элементов, куда вставляются элементы при коллизии, но не знаю как реализовать на C++.

Comment: Каждая ячейка хэш-таблицы это просто указатель на список элементов (синонимов)

Comment: @avp а отображаться они как будут?

Comment: Каждый элемент это структура, например -- `struct hash_item { uint32_t hash, Key *key, Data *data; struct hash_item *next;}`, если я правильно понял, что вы имели в виду под *`"отображаться они как будут"`*

Answer (score 0):

```
Как-то так (но здесь используется список для хранения коллизий, а не массив):

template <typename T, typename K>
class CCHash
{
private:
    int hash(int key); // функция хэширования
    List <T, K>* list; // список для хранения коллизий
public:
    T& at(K key) override; // доступ по ключу
    void add(K key, T value) override; // добавление
    void remove(K key) override; // удаление
}

template<typename T, typename K>
T& CCHash<T, K>::at(K key)
{
    return list[this->hash(key)].at(key);
}

template<typename T, typename K>
void CCHash<T, K>::add(K key, T value)
{
    list[this->hash(key)].add(key, value);
}

template<typename T, typename K>
void CCHash<T, K>::remove(K key)
{
    list[this->hash(key)].remove(key);
}
```

Comment: Это закрытое хэширование.